# Stylus doesn't compile the @media (min-width) properly

Tags: media-queries, stylus

I'm having a problem. I don't know why the Stylus isn't compiling the min-width properly when I'm using the media queries. For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px)
```

is compiling:

```
@media screen and (undefined: 1400px)
```

but when I change from min to max, it works:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px)
```

is compiling:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px)
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guess, that you have variable with same name (`min-width`). If you remove or rename it, all would be fine.